# Paste in Excel without splitting on newlines

Tags: microsoft-excel, newlines

I have some data in Google Sheets that has newlines in cells.
When I paste into Excel the data is split into rows at those newlines and the other columns remain blank on the "inserted rows".
How to prevent this splitting/row insertion and just paste normally (keeping newlines inside the cell) ?
I use Excel 2016 and it used to work correctly until a few days ago.

[image]

Comment: press F2 (or double click the cell) to edit before pasting

Comment: Try paste special all using source theme

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc I need to paste the entire sheet, not a cell at a time

Comment: oops I misread the Google Sheet part. In this case the easiest way may be exporting the sheet to file and open it in Excel for copying

Comment: I would prefer not to do that if possible. Also I am curious why on my computer is still working but on a friend's computer is not working anymore (used to work until recently). We both have 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit roundabout, but if you want some semi-automation to avoid cell-by-cell manual operations, then here's a work-around:

- Add a helper column, and use a formula to concatenates the desired rows by column
- Drag down (this assumes the number of rows per grouping is uniform, otherwise you would need additional conditional logic to delineate the lines)
- Copy the resultant column with calculated values, and paste-as-values over to another column.

It's roundabout, but at least it isn't as tedious as having to manually go in and edit all of it?  Hope this helps!